# Find newest document in MarkLogic temporal stack even if deleted

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-corb

For a CoRB collector, I need to find the newest document in their temporal stack that are not in latest. e.g. given the documents:

```
URI       Collections
A.xml     A.xml
A.1.xml   A.xml
A.2.xml   A.xml
B.xml     B.xml latest
B.1.xml   B.xml
C.xml     C.xml
```

I need a fast way to return `A.xml` and `C.xml` (but not `B.xml`)

The best I’ve come up with is to get a list of the main URIs (`A.xml B.xml C.xml`) and loop over them and then comparing the collections with the uri name. This is incredibly slow though.

Alternatively, I could create 2 corb processes; the first process to build the URIS_FILE by threading filtering and feeding that into a separate corb process. However, this adds a lot of complexity.

Is there any built-in way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [map intersection](https://www.progress.com/blogs/map-operators-use-cases) to find those URIs.

Both [`cts:uris()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris) and [`cts:collections()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:collections) have an option to get the results as a `map`. So, if you query for the URIs and the Collections that are not in the `latest` collection, and then look for the intersection - the URIs and temporal collection for that URI that match should produce those URIs. You can snag those from the resulting map with `map:keys()`

Your CoRB URIs module would be:

```
let $not-latest-query := cts:not-query(cts:collection-query("latest"))
let $uris := cts:uris("", "map", $not-latest-query)
let $collections := cts:collections("", "map", $not-latest-query)
let $most-recent-historical := map:keys($uris * $collections)
return (count($most-recent-historical), $most-recent-historical)
```

Comment: Hi @mads-hansen. If I understand correctly what you're trying to do with the `not(collection('latest'))` bit, I don't think it will work when you have at least one version of the document in addition to the latest one.  If you take Chris' example above, `B.1.xml` is in `B.xml` but not in `latest`, so it will be part of the result, won't it?

Comment: Ah, yes - you are right. I had done a quick test with dummy docs that just matched the doc collection. Seems like a regex predicate filter may be needed instead….

Comment: Well, looking at the question `b.1.xml` wasn't expected to be returned, so I think it's functioning as designed, but yes if you did want to return `b.1.xml` then you would need to do something different.

Comment: I did a sample last night based on lexicons  (`[not latest]uris` matching a collection). I also  did an Optic solution for fun.  I also started to think about `latest` and `temporal delete`.   Then I thought of the nuances in the title "MarkLogic temporal stack" and got caught up on the definition of "latest" and "newest" and decided that I was running down a rabbit hole going beyond the ask of the OP.  For the actual question asked in the context provided appears to be answered.  Great use of map operators.  This post is a great candidate for the community forum so that people could explore.